# toasts don't appear while service is running

Tags: android

I have an android service and I'd like to do the following:

When clicking a button, I start this service, the toast in the onCreate() method always appears but after that I cannot see the longitude-latitude popping up. My main goal is to use this longitude-latitude couple in more activities.

How can I achieve this?

I implemented GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,       GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location              .LocationListener because I had to wait 20-30 seconds to get the coordinates. The following code works in an activity, but not as a service.

Thanks!

**EDITED**:

```
package com.si.ou;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class FullAutoService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location
                .LocationListener {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    String loki;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        Toast.makeText(this, "service started....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (checkPermissions() && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Double lati = location.getLatitude();
        Double longi = location.getLongitude();
        loki = String.valueOf(lati) + ":" + String.valueOf(longi);
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loki, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `onLocationChanged` override even executing?

Comment: no, but i cant understand why. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are working on Service.
Try this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       getString(R.string.string_id), 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
    }
});
```

Comment: My main goal is to have a service running in the background which I can get the most current coordinates from. How could achieve this with a handler?

Comment: Inside  onLocationChanged(Location location) method where you are showing Toast. Change that line with my code.
Keep service as it is. Use Handler just to show Toast. Service will be as it is. Hence you will achieve what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I edited the code above but I still cannot see the toasts popping up. Can that be because of missing permissions or what else? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I souted something in onLocationChanged() but it doesn't even execute, that causes the problem, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Any UI component can't be accessed from background thread.
If need be arise use handler and sen msg to UI thread and update UI components.